# The independence of gradient.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Show that the curve $t \to (t, t^2, t^3)$ embeds $\mathbb{R}^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$. Find two independent functions that globally define the image. Are your functions independent on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, or just on an open neighborhood of the image?

I have problem when I try to show independence.

The two functions I am considering are
Now we consider the functions $g_1, g_2: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
g_1(x_1, x_2,x_3) & = & x_1^2 - x_2\\
g_2(x_1, x_2,x_3) & = & x_1^3 - x_3\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Then how can I show that the gradient $\nabla g_1 = (2x_1, -1, 0)$ and $\nabla g_2 = (3x_1^2, 0, -1)$ are linearly independent?

Thanks,

Comment: I think it is the second. The definition should make sense for abstract manifolds too, in which $f(x)+g(x)$ is not defined.

Comment: hmm, i guess so. so the previous one is only for real functions, right?

Comment: But there are some further issue @GiuseppeNegro, since the Jacobian of $(g_1, g_2)$ is 2-3 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector fields $\nabla g_1 = (2x_1, -1, 0)$ and $\nabla g_2 = (3x_1^2, 0, -1)$ are clearly linearly independent at each point $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$.  If not, there exist real $a, b \ne 0$
such that $a(2x_1, -1, 0) + b(3x_1^2, 0, -1) = 0$; but $a(2x_1, -1, 0) + b(3x_1^2, 0, -1) = (2ax_1 + 3bx_1^2, -a, -b)$.  If $(2ax_1 + 3bx_1^2, -a, -b) = 0$, then we must have $a = b = 0$, a conclusion which is incidentally independent of the value of the coordiante $x_1$ or even of the point  $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$!   $\nabla g_1$ and $\nabla g_2$ are linearly independent both as vector *fields* on $R^3$ and as simple vectors at each individual point.
Hope this clarifies.  Cheers.

Comment: That's really great, thanks so much! So as long as we reach the conclusion that $a=b=0$, we showed that they are independent, right? Also, I am not quite clear about what do you mean by "simple vectors at each individual point"? Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, we showed they are independent.  What I meant was:  two vector fields can be dependent at some point(s), but not everywhere, and still be globally independent.    A stronger assertion is that independence holds everywhere; that's what's wanted here, and what we have.  Hope that clarifies.  If not, let me know.  But now I'm getting sleepy . . .

Comment: Thanks @Robert. Hmm, interesting, so how come they can be dependent some point but still globally independent?